# Account is not allowed to suggest edits - Edit link disabled

Tags: support, suggested-edits

The edit button is disabled for me and on mouse over it says

> Account is not allowed to suggest edits.

I have seen people raise this question before, but I need to know exactly why my account is blocked from editing.

Comment: If too many of your edits are rejected, you are suspended from editing for a week. That is most likely the case here as well.

Comment: Have a look through your past suggested edits and try to figure out why they were rejected, if they were. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1163607/noob-unchained?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: I looked through several of your edits and it appears that about half of them have been rejected. So too many rejections is most likely the case.

Comment: @JoshMein - one-third rejected; 24 approved, 12 rejected.

Comment: It might be good to look at the rejected edits before writing this off as a bad editor. Looks like plenty of bad rejections.

Comment: Does that ban stays only for a week ? Moreover can I suggest edits in other sites of StackExchange ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained Yep, only for a week. (Of course, rejections after that will affect you once again) And it only affects your account on SO.

Comment: @BlahBlahGrabblesnackers I just checked the most recent few.

Comment: What if the rejections are prejudiced ? One such is :http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1929497 . The suggestion was turned down but eventually he edited his own post as per my suggestion ?

Comment: @JoshMein - fair enough, I just clicked the first suggested edit, and clicked "More" to expand the results and show `had 24 edit suggestions approved, and 12 edit suggestions rejected`.

Comment: @NoobUnChained No "prejudice" there. Other users rejected the edit. Then the post's OP made it himself. Fair game there. (Note: I would have agreed to that edit, since I don't like the comment either)

Comment: Might be correct but this particular comment for that rejection : "This edit plagiarizes content from an external source without proper attribution." is beyond my comprehension !

Comment: @NoobUnChained Yep, no clue what on earth that is about. Perhaps he means there is a problem with the answer itself? No clue really.

Comment: Looking at some of your recent rejected edits, I see these two: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1930795 , http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1933267 , where while you cleaned up some of the language, you also removed details of the question in the process. When editing, you need to try to retain the core spirit and information of the question. I can see why those edits might have been rejected.

Comment: Goodness gracious ! Now MetaSO says that "we are no longer accepting questions from this account " ! Why is that so ? Does it assume my poor self to be a bot ?

Comment: -10, -20, -3 and two duplicates....that might have triggered the question ban.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because too many of your recent edits have been rejected; see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1933267),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1931525),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1930795),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1929497),[5](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1923180).

Reviewers often rejected your edits for "This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post". Looks like the edit you made are changing the meaning and that is something that is not wanted on the site.

Maybe you should comment on post rather than try to edit them sometimes.

I'm not saying you made only bad edits but sometimes, you should choose posts where there are a lot to improve rather than just a word or a sentence. This will help reduce the rate of rejection for too minor. Also, if you see that you change a lot of words (to rephrase stuff better), it might be a good idea to make longer comments on the edit to show that you didn't change the meaning, but only rephrase.

---

Also by pressing the <kbd>more</kbd> link on an edit you can see your stats (which are currently 24 accepted and 12 refused).

Comment: That sums up to 2/3rd accepted , but still a ban ! What is the threshold in terms of percentages of rejected edits out of the total suggested ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained I'm not sure those stats are public. And it probably includes more factor! Like a X rejected on Y over Z days.